# Disable selection of textarea but still allow typing?

Tags: javascript, css, textarea

I'm trying to disable the ability for a user to select the text that they put in to a textarea. There is a [question similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162175/jquery-disable-select-allow-input) to this but I've fiddled around on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbzM6/8/) and can't get it to work properly. I need it so that if a user tries to select user submitted text in a text area with either Ctrl+A or by the mouse, they can't, (without disabling the ability to type in the first place).

I tried the

```
    *.unselectable {
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
```

CSS method but that doesn't seem to work at all. Really stuck on this, is it even possible?

Comment: I thinks it's a bad UI behaviour, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is another solution

Comment: In any case, anyone with access to the browsers developer tools will be able to bypass any JS/CSS limitations... What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: do you want to disable copy-paste,select all? tell why u need this

Comment: It's intentionally dysfunctional, I'm trying to recreate a typewriter but in an app. I've disabled backspace etc but there's  still the issue of a user selecting all the text and then typing new characters that replace old ones...

Comment: @JackClarke - What about receiving input from the user character by character but displaying the content in an un-editable element - such as a `<div>` or `<span>`?

Comment: @Lix that's a good shout, I'll give that a go thanks for the idea